# Should I remove all installed gems now that I'm planning on using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rvm

I'm setting up RoR on my machine for the first time. I've gone through a couple of tutorials, and have installed some dependencies for each of them.

I haven't run into any issues yet, but having enjoyed using VirutalEnv for Python, I'm thinking that it'd be best to use RVM, based on my experience.

The question is as follows: will keeping these existing gems outside of their own unique environment cause problems for me in the long run, and thus I should remove all gems of this nature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not. RVM creates a isolated environment for each gemset so there will be no interference from old gems outside your gemsets. You don't even have to use RVM, bundler will work a long way alone.

Also, welcome to another Rails developer, we are glad to have you! :D